# How to get NSDictionary data into a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

I have 2 NSArrays that I'm trying to link together in an NSDictionary so that each **providerName** has a **providerId** associated with it.

I expected the two arrays to be associated with each other using `self.providersDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:providerName forKeys:providerId];` and then the providerName to be displayed as the table cell title and the id as the table cell subtitle.

At the moment I can't get the data  displayed on the UITable or even log out the dictionary using:

```
   for (id key in self.providersDict) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [self.providersDict objectForKey:key]);
}
```

declared in the .h:

```
NSArray *providerName;
NSArray *providerId;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *providersDict;
```

and in the viewDidLoad:

```
    providerName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"provider1", @"provider2", @"provider3", nil];
    providerId = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];

    self.providersDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:providerName
                                                           forKeys:providerId];
```

the UITable methods:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self.providersDict allKeys] count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



 static NSString *unifiedID = @"aCellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:unifiedID];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:unifiedID];

}

for (id key in self.providersDict) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [self.providersDict objectForKey:key]);
}

NSString *providerNameString = [self.providersDict objectForKey:@"provider"];
NSString *providerIdString = [self.providersDict objectForKey:@"object"];
cell.textLabel.text  = providerNameString;
cell.detailTextLabel.text  = providerIdString;


return cell;

}
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: What is your requirement ? Could you please explain me ?

Comment: I thought the above would work. I expected the two arrays to be associated with each other using  self.providersDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:providerName
                                                           forKeys:providerId]; and then the providerName to be displayed as the table cell title and the id as the table cell subtitle. the nslog statement didn't run. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I assume there is not key named "object" and "provider" in your providersDict , keys are 1,2,3 ? and you cant enumerate dictionary as you are trying to do for logs....

Comment: I think your keys and values in the dictionary are interchanged. Check that.

Comment: Did you set the delegate for tableView? I dont think your delegate methods are getting called

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
NSString *providerNameString = [self.providersDict objectForKey:@"provider"];
NSString *providerIdString = [self.providersDict objectForKey:@"object"];
```

You have initialized self.providersDict with keys 1, 2, 3. So you should Try to fetch `providerNameString` using those keys and not `@"provider"` same for `providerIdString`.

Try

```
NSString *key = [self.providersDict allKeys][indexPath.row];

NSString *providerNameString = self.providersDict[key];
NSString *providerIdString = key;
cell.textLabel.text  = providerNameString;
cell.detailTextLabel.text  = providerIdString;
```

And don't forget to call `[tableView reloadData];` once your `self.providersDict` is initialized.

As for a suggestion why dont you create a Model Class for `Provider` with id, name and other information. You can add each provider in an array and would make your life a lot easier.

Comment: You already thanked me by upvoting. But again if you can try to create a model object for Provider :)

Answer (score -2):

For your purpose , you don't need any `NSDictionary` , simply use two `NSArrays` to populate the data in `UITableView`

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *unifiedID = @"aCellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = 
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:unifiedID];

    if (!cell) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:unifiedID];  
    }

    NSString *providerNameString = [providerName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *providerIdString = [providerId objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text  = providerNameString;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text  = providerIdString;
    return cell;
}
```